# A data structure to do a specific lookup fast

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms

I have 30,000 items; each item has 30 parameters that take values from 0 to 5. These parameters are named $p_0$ to $p_{29}$ and their value is an integer between 0 and 5. I want to store these items in a data structure where I can do this lookup quickly: find the parameter with a given value for $(p_0, \ldots, p_{29})$.

All items that have $p_i$ less than or equal $x_i$.

So having 50 values $x_0$ to $x_{29}$ I run the above lookup and it returns all items that satisfy it. I used PostgreSQL and created indices for each of these parameters. Querying in PostgreSQL happens in ~20ms. I stored them in a Python list and did a simple `[i for i in items if all(i['p' + str(j)] < n[j] for j in range(30))]` and it takes ~250ms. By using 30 dicts each containing 6 sets for different values of each parameter and doing the lookup in dicts and intersecting sets I was able to each ~10ms (a bit memory consuming but not that much). Does anyone know about a better data structure to do this query faster? Memory is not an issue as long as it's below 2GB.

In formal language I'd describe it this way:
I have 30,000 records; each record contains 30 values, each in range 0..5:

```
type Record: array[1..30] of 0..5
var Store: array[1..30000] of Record
```

I need to find all records in the store, where each element is smaller than in the target one:

```
procedure Find(target: Record):
  for item in Store:
    if item[0]<=target[0] and item[1]<=target[1] and ... and item[30]<=target[30]: 
      print item
```

I need to perform Find quick, and can preprocess the Store to make the lookups faster. What data structure and algorithm can I use?

Comment: Please don't just reply to a comment: also edit your question to add the information. I've edited your question based on my understanding of your comment. Please review and correct it if that wasn't what you meant.

Comment: As a practical matter, this is the kind of problem that databases were made to solve, so you may have a hard time beating a database engine at its own game..

Comment: @Gilles thanks for the edit. Yeah usually databases are supposed to solve these kind of problems, but considering that my dataset is static and never changes and considering the low number of rows and the fact that the lookup is a special kind of lookup it should be possible to beat database engines (at least those that store in disc) my answer and Bulat's answer are 2 examples of how to do better than database engines.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the parameter with a given value for $(p_0, \ldots, p_{29})$"?  Do you mean "find the *item* with a given value for $(p_0, \ldots, p_{29})$?  I don't understand what "All items that have pi less than or equal xi." is communicating.  That is not a complete sentence, and it's not clear how it relates to anything else.  Please edit your question to specify your task more clearly.

Comment: @D.W. For a given sequence x_0 to x_49 (with values between 0 to 5) I want all items like ITEM in the list of items that satisfy the condition "for all i in range [0, 49], ITEM.p_i is less than or equal x_i".

Comment: As Gilles [already explained](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97073/a-data-structure-to-do-a-specific-lookup-fast?noredirect=1#comment206661_97073), please don't just reply by leaving a comment.  Instead, edit the question.  Revise the question so it is self-contained and so it incorporates all relevant information.  People should not have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think the question needs any edits, what I wrote here was a clarification just for you, someone already answered this question with its current state. If you think it has room for improvement feel free to improve it but in my personal judgment it's currently alright with my poor knowledge of English language and I don't think I have the time to edit it. But i'm willing to clarify it in comments for people who need comments about it. @D.W.

Comment: While I understood our question, it's not because it's clearly described but because I spent more efforts. So, yet, it' still not very readable. By making question easier to understand, you may approach wider audience, and have a chance to find smarter CS solution rather than brute-force one.

Comment: On other stack exchange sites usually people take action (editorial action) when they see there's room for improvement rather than asking others to apply the improvements they think there's room for. I think cs.stackexchange should follow that pattern too because when someone can't state a question clearly, it's probably because of their lingual skills and the fact that they're not native English speakers (like the case here.) so when you understand the question in comments, you can go ahead and edit the question. Asking the op to edit it himself probably won't help as his edit will probably->

Comment: -> introduce other ambiguities while clearing some. I think if someone tries to state something and can't do it, naturally I'll try to help him state it instead of obsessively asking him to refine his main statement over and over till it satisfies my standards unless I'm teaching them the language which is not the case in cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Btw none of above implies that I'm willing to brute force a solution rather than examining different solutions. I haven't accepted an answer as the correct answer so far just cause I think there are yet other solutions for this problem and I'm willing to examine those solutions too.

Comment: I understand if you don't have time to edit it; time is precious.  You might be more likely to get others to volunteer their time to help you find a better solution if you can edit it to improve.  If you don't want to spend the time to make it easy for others to help you, that's your choice, but it might affect whether others want to spend their time to understand the question and answer.

Comment: @Sassan I added possibly better description of the question at the end, it's up to you to combine the final text.

Comment: @Bulat thanks, if we wanted to go with the "edit this part" then "edit that part" procedure we wouldn't reach what we reached now with your edit. I could never describe it with the formal language you described it. I learnt from your edit and I'm sure my next question will be more readable using the things I learnt from your edit. I think your edit was more practical and much faster approach to make this question understandable for readers.

Comment: @D.W. Sincerely I think you replied to an interpretation of my comment that's based on your assumptions and I think those assumptions aren't true. If I wasn't willing to spend time I wouldn't come back here to share the solution I found in an answer. I wouldn't comment on Bulat's solution, I wouldn't discuss these things here. All of above took time and I spent that time to not only solve my problem (the solution I provided below is enough for my real world problem.) but to add value to this thread for others and to discuss and try to improve the procedures in cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To add value for others, and for myself of course.

Answer (score 2):

Using SSE2 operations, you can save the entire dataset in 512 KB and search through it, with 4-core CPU, is less than 10 microseconds.

PCMPB+PMOVMSKB instructions will give you 16-bit mask made from 16 byte-wide comparisons. You need to combine two such masks as a<<16+b and make sure that result is all 0s.

---

Even faster approach is to make bitmap for each `p[i]<k` condition, overall you need 30*6=180 bitmaps. Each bitmap takes 30K/8=3.75 KB, overall 675 KB.

You need to AND-combine 30 maps corresponding to chosen x[i], i.e. AND-process 675/6=112.5 KB of data. With 128-bit SSE operations, this requires 7K operations, and on the same 4-core CPU, it's less than microsecond long.

Comment: Even checking this solution is hard for me, but if correct, it's a perfect solution. specially I like the second solution you provided. For first solution I need to research a bit to understand it so that I can check it and mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Sassan The second solution is faster and easier to understand. I think that even with pure Python, it can work faster than your ideas. Or you can write a bit of C code, or find a library dealing with bit arrays (or just supporting AND operation on arrays of ints), or use a Python compiler with static typing.

Comment: @Sassan now you may need to ask Python community where you can find fast bit array implementation, may be there is something right in built-in libraries.

Comment: using this for my real world problem is definitely overkill, so I'm not trying to use it with python. I'll check it with C next free weekend.

Comment: @Sassan googling "bitset python" i found https://intbitset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - if you spend more time you may find even better solutions. Key point should be the speed of iterating over resulting bitset

Answer (score 1):

This is how I optimized it so far: created python dictionary that contains 30 keys for 30 parameters, each value is another dict that contains keys from 0 to 5 (including) for different values each parameter can take. then the values of this final dicts are sets that include indices of the items in original list of items. To look up the query, I simply intersect the relevant sets finding them with fast dict lookups. To optimize it further I sort sets that I want to intersect by their size before intersecting them so that intersections happen with smaller sets.

Suppose that all items are stored in list `L`:

```
L = [
    {"entry":"e1","p0":0,"p1":2,"p2":3,"p4":0,...}.
    {"entry":"e2","p0":5,"p1":1,"p2":0,"p4":4,...},
...
]
```

I build the above mentioned dict like this:

```
index = {p + str(i): {
            j: {k for k in range(len(words))
                if words[k]['p' + str(i)] <= j} for j in range(5)
        } for i in range(30)}
```

It just runs once and takes few seconds. Then to lookup I run:

```
[L[i]['entry'] for i in sorted(functools.reduce(
            operator.and_,
            sorted(
                [index[p + str(i)][x[i]]
                    for i in range(30)],
                key=lambda set: len(set),
            ),
        ))]
```

It runs in ~5ms and is 4 times better than Postgresql results (as expected because it runs in memory with no disc usage.)
But I think it's not smart enough, I'm consuming lots of memory, it's alright for 30,000 items and only 5 values which is the requirements of my real world problem, but I'm still curious to know if this problem has a better solution with less memory usage or even faster?

Comment: How about using a kd-tree (or quadtree, R-Tree, ...)? Your items can be stored as 3-dimensional data points/vectors...